# Integrate local HDFS filesystem browser with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: hadoop, intellij-idea, filesystems, remote-access

I studied MapReduce paradigm using the HDFS cluster of my university, accessing to it by HUE. From HUE I am able to browse files, read/edit them and so on.

So in that cluster I need:

- a normal folder where I put the MapReduce.jar
- the access to the results in the HDFS

I like very much write MapReduce applications so I have configured correctly a local HDFS as personal playground but for now I can access to it only thorough really time-wasting command line (such as [those](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html)).

I can access "directly" to the HDFS of my thorough IntelliJ IDEA by the mean of SFTP remote host connection, following is the "user normal folder":

[image]

And here is the HDFS from HUE from which I get the results:

[image]

Obviously in my local machine the "normal user folder" is where I am with the shell, but I can browse HDFS to get results only by command line.

I wish I could do such a thing even for local HDFS. Following is the best I could do:

[image]

I know that it is possible to access HDFS by http://localhost:50070/explorer.html#/ but it is very terrible.

I looked for some plugins, but I did not find anything useful. Using the command line in the long run becomes tiring.

Comment: For a while i looked at "http://gethue.com/start-developing-hue-on-a-mac-in-a-few-minutes/" but i wait a bit more for someone that could post a better solutions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can access "directly" to the HDFS of my thorough IntelliJ IDEA by the mean of SFTP remote host ...
>
> Following is the best I could do...

**Neither** of those are HDFS.

1. Is the user folder of the machine you SSH'd to
2. Is only the NameNode data directory on your local machine

Hue uses WebHDFS, and connects through `http://namenode:50070`

What you would need is a plugin that can [connect to the same API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#List_a_Directory), which is not over SSH, or a simple file mount.

If you wanted a file mount, you need to setup an [NFS Gateway](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html), and you [mount the NFS drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269285/macos-sierra-mounting-nfs-volumes) like any other network attached storage.

In Production environments, you would write your code, push it to Github, then Jenkins (for example) would build the code and push it to HDFS for you.